# Probability law of large numbers

Tags: probability

Prove that if for every n, var (Xi) <= C < infinity and cov (Xi, Xj) <0 (i, j =1,2,....) then the weak law of large numbers holds.

Comment: You might want to search for other Questions and Answers related to the Law of Large Numbers.  Your own problem seems poorly stated; you introduce the requirement that something holds "for every n", but $n$ does not appear elsewhere in your short post.  Please think through what you want to ask after researching the previous material on Math.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows by Chebyshev's inequality. Are you familiar to that?

Let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$. Observe that
$$
Var(S_n) = \mathbb{E} \left(  S_n - \mathbb{E}[S_n]\right)^2 < \sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) < Cn.
$$
Since the $cov(X_i, X_j)$ is negative for all $i$ and $j$ and $Var(X_i) < C$ for all $i$.
Now, for a fixed positive small $\epsilon$, we have by Chebyshev
$$
P\left( \left|\frac{S_n - \mathbb{E}[S_n]}{n}\right| > \epsilon \right) \le \frac{Var(S_n)}{\epsilon^2n^2} < \frac{Cn}{\epsilon^2n^2} = \frac{C}{\epsilon^2n}.
$$

If you are not familiar with the inequality I've just mentioned maybe you should take a look at Wikipedia.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly about  E(Sn−E[Sn])2<∑i=1nVar(Xi). Why we have this inequality ???

Comment: @NguyenNganha expand the squared term and use the linearity of the expected value.

Comment: Can you send me the formula ???

Comment: @NguyenNganha of course not. You should try it by yourself.

Comment: Sorry !!! I have done that but my friend using my account to ask you. Thank you for the first comment ^^